# AgoraIO Web + Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack, agora.io

I'm trying to push github repo [LargeGroupVideoChat-Web-Webpack](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Advanced-Video/tree/master/Web/LargeGroupVideoChat-Web-Webpack) to Heroku.
Locally it works fine, with these scripts in package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config ./scripts --mode development",
"build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./scripts --mode production"},
```

And webpack settings in index.js file:

```
module.exports = {
 entry: {
   index: "./src/index.js",
 },
 devtool: "inline-source-map",
 module: loaders,
 plugins,
 resolve: {
   extensions: [ ".js" ],
 },
 output: {
   filename: "[name].[hash].js",
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, distPath),
 }, ...
```

However, after pushing to Heroku it crashes with error. I added server.js file with this code:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();

// the __dirname is the current directory from where the script is running
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

// send the user to index html page inspite of the url
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port);
```

It runs ok, but it only serves index.html file, and webpack bundle is not linked. Is there a fast way to push the app to Heroku? Or I have to rewrite webpack settings somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the server.js file solved the problem (from [another](https://github.com/darde/phaser-heroku-webpack-es6) repo):

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('listening on port ', server.address().port);
});
```